# How can pass variable inside _.find function's condition field

Tags: angularjs, lodash

How can pass variable inside _.find function's condition field

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
];
var field='age';
var result=_.find(users, { field : 36, 'active': true });

 console.log(result);
```

Comment: The same way you pass a variable to any other function. What is your concrete question? What does the code you posted has to do with your question?

Comment: @JBNizet No its not working. getting undefined

Comment: OK. I start understanding what you're asking. Unsure why your question talks about find, when your code calls filter, though.

Comment: If you're happy using ES6 then you could use the property expression setter: `{ [field]: 36, ...}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
];
var field = 'age';
var criteria = { active: true };
criteria[field] = 36;
var result = _.filter(users, criteria);

console.log(result);
```